Select insert for multiple rows by setting max id is getting the same id
I have a master table and a copy table. When master table inserted_dt is todays date, I want to insert those rows.
But when inserting I want to increase copy table id from current max id + 1.
At the moment if there are 3 rows which inserted_dt is todays date, below query inserted with same id which only increased once.
example
insert copyTable (id, name, cusId)
select (select max(id) + 1 from copyTable), mst.name, mst.cusId
from  copyTable cpy
right join masterTable mst on cpy.cusId = mst.cusId
where mst.inserted_dt = @todayDate

Actual Result



id
name
cusId




190(current max id)
**
**


191(inserted id)
**
**


191(inserted id)
**
**


191(inserted id)
**
**



Expected Result



id
name
cusId




190(current max id)
**
**


191(inserted id)
**
**


192(inserted id)
**
**


193(inserted id)
**
**



How can I implement to get my expected result. I look for many solution (like row_number()) on so but none meet with my need.

Row_number is one way to do it, soemthing like (select max(ID) from somewhere) + row_number() over(order by something)

No it is getting error like Subquery returned more than 1 value...

Then you need to show us the query that is returning that error, because it needs fixing, but we can only help you fix it if you show us.

Sory I got it !! I remove extra select before row_number() .. Thanks

Why all the hassle? Why not just make the ID an identity column (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver16) as is common? The only difference is that you might get gaps, but it's just an ID, so who cares?

And why a right outer join? Your join equals from masterTable mst left join copyTable cpy on cpy.cusId = mst.cusId, which is easier to read. So you are doing this in order to multiply the masterTable rows with the number of copyTable rows with the same cusId? So the first time you insert a row with cusID = 1, you insert it once, the next time you insert the new row again once, the third time you insert it twice, the fourth time thrice. That is a strange requirement. Be aware that if you insert two or more rows with the same cusID at once, that they will be multiplied with the same factor.

By adding the result of the subquery and the row number, each new row gets a unique ID starting from the current maximum ID + 1.
INSERT INTO copyTable (id, name, cusId)
SELECT
    (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) FROM copyTable) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mst.cusId)
    , mst.name
    , mst.cusId
FROM masterTable mst
WHERE mst.inserted_dt = @todayDate;


This appears to be identical to the existing answer? What are you offering that that one doesn't?

I refined the code with proper error handling machanism,

The subquery (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(id), 0) FROM copyTable) ensures that if copyTable is empty, it returns 0.

In that case, please edit your answer and explain that, because otherwise it looks like you copied the other answer.

max(id)+1, will give same number only across all the new rows. To generate unique id values for each row, you can use the ROW_NUMBER() function as in below code:
Code:
DECLARE @todayDate DATE =  getdate();
INSERT INTO copyTable (id, name, cusId)
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM copyTable) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mst.cusId)
    , mst.name
    , mst.cusId
FROM copyTable cpy
RIGHT JOIN masterTable mst
    ON cpy.cusId = mst.cusId
WHERE mst.inserted_dt = @todayDate;

fiddle
